# Lightbox - how to move image count to top of image

Tags: position, lightbox

I'm using Lightbox to create a gallery for my website and I want to move the image counter and close image to the top of my image but keep the caption at the bottom. Help! I've searched the web and the closest I've found was on here explaining how to move the image counter, caption and close button to the top by swapping the outercontainer and datacontainer but I only want to move the counter and close.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218860/lightbox-2-51-how-to-move-close-button-and-image-number-to-the-top